# Match dot in the end of a word in my case

Tags: regex

I'm almost there but I'm stuck at match the last dot of a word

I want to match `Feat.`

Comment: Where is your test corpus?

Comment: your regex seems unrelated.

Comment: forget it without trying to spend some effort with yourself first.

Comment: @Sam can I exclude the word Feat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to match a `.` at the end of a word, you can use a word boundary `\b`:

```
\b\.
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/nS8qB8/2)

---

`\b` is a zero-length assertion (it finds, but does not match) that checks for the point between a word (`\w`) and a non-word (`\W`). `\w` is shorthand for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and `\W` is the opposite.

If you want to be more specific as to what makes a "word", you can use a different zero-length assertion: a lookbehind (`(?<=...)`). The next example works the same as the first, but it makes sure there is a lowercase letter before the period we match:

```
(?<=[a-z])\.
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/nS8qB8/3)